# Can i offset soft body simulation start?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data, soft-body

I have a rope and i am using soft body simulation to animate it. For the first 80 frames rope is twitching before it gets to it's physically-correct resting state. I don't need that 80 frames in my scene, only the animation that goes afterwards. [image: Rope gets to resting state] Can i somehow get the state of that rope on frame 80, bring it to frame 1 and continue the simulation with the same parameters from there?

I've tried to apply soft-body modifier on frame 80. It saved the result but the rope became static. Then i decided to duplicate the rope, apply modifier on one of them and then link modifiers from the animated one. Didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way, but if you bake the simulation, you can begin the animation on whatever frame you want and the results will behave like a scripted sequence that can be scrubbed through on the timeline and never deviate from the established course. You can have a frame range set in the Render Properties that tells Blender to begin rendering on frame 80. How would this not  achieve what you actually want? Why is it necessary to begin from frame one? It seems to me that only the rendered output matters in the end.

Comment: I've thought about it. But I have objects, that follow bezier curve. They start at frame 1, and finish at the given frame. I've tried to make them start at frame 80, but couldn't do that.

Comment: I've never tried this, but I wonder if you can start the simulation before frame 1.